# How to train HOG + Cascade

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, svm, face-detection, adaboost

I want to try HOG+Cascade which was proposed in `Fast Human Detection Using a Cascade of Histograms of Oriented Gradients`. It used **line-SVM** to train the weak classifier in each stage of Adaboost.
**But How to count the weight of sample into the Line-SVM.** If don't count. It will get the same result with same features.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, the **linear** SVM was used by Zhu et al. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the weight of a simple.

If you are referring to the *dual weights* -- commonly denoted by alpha, those are the direct result of training the SVM.

Comment: what does dual weights mean. After one stage of AdaBoost, You should update the weights of sample. And In the next stage. You should learn a new weak classifier based on the new weights. I mean How to count this weights into the line SVM.